# Does Heroku provide capabilities for remote debugging for Ruby applications?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubymine

I'm interested in remote debugging from RubyMine, where is Ruby Remote Debug configuration is used for it. I see mentions about Node.js, Java in Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#remote-debugging)  and no one about Ruby. 
I tried to follow RubyMine [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging.html) and decidied to install ruby-debug-ide inside Heroku dynos through Personal apps -> ruby-app -> Run console -> heroku run bash -> gem install ruby-debug-ide, which is failed with messages:

> "ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide: 
>    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Eventually, please let me know if:

- Heroku allows to debug Ruby apps remotely
- it possible to install ruby-debug-ide inside dyno

Thanks in advance.